# First service always coming up as unknown

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Whichever factory is listed first is always getting this error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: SocketProvider <- Socket
```

at `ionic.bundle.js:13380`

or

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: CommandsProvider <- Commands <- Command
```

at `ionic.bundle.js:25642`

If it's put in one file like the starters are, they work fine, but that organization is horrible and this is the way I do it with regular Angular apps.

**INDEX:**

```
<script src="app.js"></script>
<script src="services/socket.service.js"></script>
<script src="services/commands.service.js"></script>
<script src="controllers/connect.controller.js"></script>
<script src="controllers/command.controller.js"></script>
```

**Service structure:**

*socket.service.js*

```
(function(){
  'use strict';

  angular.module('tacoCorp.services', [])
    .factory('Socket', Socket);

  Socket.$inject = ['socketFactory'];

  function Socket(socketFactory) {
    // do factory stuff
  }
}());
```

*commands.service.js*

```
(function(){
  'use strict';

  angular.module('tacoCorp.services', [])
    .factory('Commands', Commands);

  Commands.$inject = [];

  function Commands() {
    // more factory stuff
  }
}());
```

**Controller structure:**

```
(function (){
  'use strict';

  angular.module('tacoCorp.controllers')
    .controller('Command', Command);

  Command.$inject = ['$scope', 'Socket', 'Commands'];

  function Command($scope, Socket, Commands) {
    // controller jamz  
  }

})();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually define module `'tacaCorp.services'` two times thats why first module is overwritten...

You should write module defination in another file then get it at services js files...

```
(function(){
  'use strict';

  angular.module('tacoCorp.services', []);

}());
```

as you see we define module with no dependency. Next get module and add your services on it.

```
(function(){
  'use strict';

  angular.module('tacoCorp.services')
    .factory('Commands', Commands);

  Commands.$inject = [];

  function Commands() {
    // more factory stuff
  }
}());
```

**as you see for getting module you only have to call `angular.module('tacoCorp.services')` like that if you add second argument then you set it instead of get it, this is your mistake actually.**

Comment: So really I just have to take off the `[]` from every subsequent services because the first one is actually defining it?

Comment: yes you only need to define module one time then you can get same module anywhere...

Comment: Ok, great. That makes sense. Thank you, sir.